# How to create folders & subfolders in Excel using cell value

Tags: excel, vba

How do I make this code use the value in cell J2 to make a sub folder so when the year rolls around I can just change the date in cell J2 without having to go into the code?

Here is all the  code:

```
     Sub IfNewFolder()
   Dim R As Range
   Dim RootFolder As String
   RootFolder = "R:\Sales\Quotes (Commercial)\" '<<< CHANGE 1
   For Each R In Range("D1") '<<< CHANGE 2


       If Len(R.Text) > 0 Then
           On Error Resume Next
           MkDir RootFolder & "\" & R.Text
           MkDir RootFolder & "\" & R.Text & "\2019"

           On Error GoTo 0
       End If
   Next R
      End Sub
```

How do I remove `MkDir RootFolder & "\" & r.Text & ("\2019")` and make it use the value in Cell J2 for that folder name.

Thanks,

Lamar

Comment: Where do you set `r` and declare `RootFolder`?  In any case, you could do `MkDir Range("J2") & "\" & r.Text & "\2018"`...

Comment: Is J2 going to contain the full path/file name?  Or, is J2 going to contain the year only?

Comment: Curious what you're up to that the year 2018 hasnt rolled over yet

Comment: The `Next r` doesn't have a matching `For`. Please provide the whole code that pertains to this. As @BruceWayne asked, where is `r` coming from and what is `RootFolder` defined as?

Comment: J2 will just have the year in that cell. D1 creates a folder with the contents from that cell.

Comment: Thanks, that worked

Answer (score 0):

It's easy enough to add J2 to your code:

```
Sub IfNewFolder()
Dim R As Range
Dim RootFolder As String
Dim CurrYear as String

RootFolder = "R:\Sales\Quotes (Commercial)\" '<<< CHANGE 1
CurrYear = "\" & Range("J2").Value

For Each R In Range("D1") '<<< CHANGE 2
   If Len(R.Text) > 0 Then
       On Error Resume Next
       MkDir RootFolder & "\" & R.Text
       MkDir RootFolder & "\" & R.Text & CurrYear

       On Error GoTo 0
   End If
Next R
End Sub
```

I would suggest specifying your range a bit,
instead of just using `Range("D1")` I would use `Workbooks(Thisworkbook.name).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D1")`,
In your for loop state it as:

```
 For Each R in Workbooks(Thisworkbook.name).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D1:D10")
 'Rest of loop code here
 Next R
```

Also, if you are only looking at D1, you don't need to have a loop for it,
you can simply set R to D1 then check if its .Text length is 0.